# boost iostreams compilation error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compilation, iostream

this is my compile line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -lboost_iostreams cppfile.cpp -o bin
```

but I have the following error:

```
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `trie::write_on_disk(char*)':
undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy'
undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated'
undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_compressor<std::allocator<char> >::basic_gzip_compressor(boost::iostreams::gzip_params const&, int)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:671: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::best_compression'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:671: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::best_speed'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::zlib_compressor_impl(boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:338: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::zlib_base()'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:338: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::~zlib_compressor_impl()':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:343: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:343: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `void boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::init<std::allocator<char> >(boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&, bool, boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_allocator<std::allocator<char>, boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::type>&)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:185: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::do_init(boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&, bool, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int), void (*)(void*, void*), void*)'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::filter(char const*&, char const*, char*&, char*, bool)':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:350: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::before(char const*&, char const*, char*&, char*)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:351: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::finish'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:351: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::no_flush'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:351: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::xdeflate(int)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:352: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::after(char const*&, char*&, bool)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:353: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib_error::check(int)'
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:354: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::zlib::stream_end'
/tmp/cclste3G.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::close()':
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp:358: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)'
```

I use -lboost_iostreams so I don't understrand why I have this error

Regards

Comment: Does it work if you put `-lboost_iostreams` after `cppfile.cpp`?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine yes it work :D thanks! How is it possible ^^"

Comment: @perecastor : Order of linker flags is significant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this by putting the linker flag `-lboost_iostreams` after `cppfile.cpp`. The order is significant.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Before all please install zlib library
apt-get install zlib1g
apt-get install zlib1g-dev

#Try to add [ -lz ] option in command line
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -lboost_iostreams -lz cppfile.cpp -o bin

#If mentioned don't work, find exact position of libz.so and add -L option in command line 
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -lboost_iostreams -lz cppfile.cpp -o bin -L/usr/share
```